# Group a set of events by time interval (no panda)

Tags: python, list

I'm searching for an intelligent way to group a set of events.
Let's say I have this set:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Event:
   name: str
   timestamp: datetime

d = datetime(2021, 3, 24, 10, 0, 0, 0)  # 24.03.2021 10:00

events = {
   Event('A', d + timedelta(seconds=10)),  # 24.03.2021 10:10
   Event('B', d + timedelta(seconds=15)),  # 24.03.2021 10:15
   Event('C', d + timedelta(seconds=20)),  # 24.03.2021 10:20
   Event('D', d + timedelta(seconds=45)),  # 24.03.2021 10:45
   Event('E', d + timedelta(seconds=50)),  # 24.03.2021 10:50
   Event('F', d + timedelta(days=1, seconds=10)),  # 25.03.2021 10:10
   Event('G', d + timedelta(days=1, seconds=15)),  # 25.03.2021 10:15
   Event('H', d + timedelta(days=2, seconds=35)),  # 26.03.2021 10:35
   Event('I', d + timedelta(days=2, seconds=40))  # 26.03.2021 10:40
}
```

What I now want to do is to group those events by there occurrence. This means I want to group the events by the time passing between those events. In example, I want to group events which occur in 5 seconds after a previous event. The result should then look like this:

```
result = {
   {Event('A'), Event('B'), Event('C')},
   {Event('D'), Event('E')},
   {Event('F'), Event('G')},
   {Event('H'), Event('I')}
}
```

I think I can use the `itertools.groupby` function for that. I found a lot of topics about it, but not my specific case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I have a look at the `itertools.groupby` and think it may not be the best for the job as you have to compare with the previous timestamp. Here is what I think is the best:

```
#sort the list of events by timestamp
data = sorted(list(events), key=lambda x: x.timestamp)

delay_interval = 5 #seperate by 5s
collection = []
group = set()
previous = data[0]
for event in data:
    if (event.timestamp - previous.timestamp).total_seconds() <= delay_interval:
        group.add(event)
    else:
        collection.append(group)
        group = {event}
    previous = event
```

Here is the collection you get:

```
[{Event(name='A', timestamp=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 24, 10, 0, 10)),
  Event(name='B', timestamp=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 24, 10, 0, 15)),
  Event(name='C', timestamp=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 24, 10, 0, 20))},
 {Event(name='D', timestamp=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 24, 10, 0, 45)),
  Event(name='E', timestamp=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 24, 10, 0, 50))},
 {Event(name='F', timestamp=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 25, 10, 0, 10)),
  Event(name='G', timestamp=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 25, 10, 0, 15))}]
```

Comment: Yes, I looked a little bit deeper into the itertools.groupby function and also saw that it is not usable here. Thank you. Solution accepted.